# EntityFramework - Method not found: 'System.Threading.Tasks<TSource> System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.FirstOrDefaultAsync...'

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I'm using Entity Framework 6.1.0 in several apps, and the below  error shows for each app I try to run on Localhost:

Method not found: 'System.Threading.Tasks System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.FirstOrDefaultAsync...'

Currently targeting .Net 4.5.

Has anyone else seen this error?

Have a feeling it's related to DLLs in the GAC or somewhere else, but not seeing any conflicts in Fusion Log Viewer.

Comment: Not sure if this will help since it was unresolved, but you can have a look at the comments to see if this is applicable: https://forums.asp.net/t/2044515.aspx?+FirstOrDefaultAsync+method+not+found

Comment: That's actually the first thread I found before posting here. This is a new machine, so unfortunately the suggestion didn't help.

Comment: If it's a new machine it will probably be faster to re-install OS, than to find out the reason.

Comment: have you checked all your nuget packages

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh If it's a new machine, then how would reinstalling the OS help in this situation?

Comment: @PreetSingh Yes, and EntityFramework.dll is in the Debug folder when running the app.

Comment: @user2966445 by getting the installation into a fresh state. Yours is not in a fresh state right now, on the opposite it sounds like it's crewed up. This is indicated by the problem you are having

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh Reinstalling isn't really an option, since it's a company laptop.

Comment: have the same issue,

Comment: @CMS The issue was related to an older DLL in the GAC or .Net Temporary Files folder

Comment: @user2966445 Could you please elaborate how you solved the issue with the GAC / .NET Temporary Files folder? We are currently facing something similar and we suspect that is has to do with the .NET Runtime loading the wrong version of EntityFramework.dll. The difference is that we're not running ASP.NET in IIS, but a WPF application accessing the database directly. Thus I think the .NET Temporary Files folder does not apply as it is IIS-specific?

Comment: @user2966445 can this problem be circumvented by setting 'Specific Version' to 'True' in the properties of a reference? I think this way the corresponding GAC DLL would not be loaded as it does not suffice the version constraint. Unfortunately, we do not have access to the client's computer that cannot start our application, thus we cannot manipulate its GAC.